# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^\alpha \Big(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{n+1} - \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\Big)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $\alpha$ be a positive number. Find $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^\alpha \Big(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{n+1} - \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\Big).$$

I'd love to post a useful solution attempt, but all of my efforts seem far off. :)

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: You may want to use this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation

Comment: My attempts to use Stirling's approximation have been in vain.

Comment: is $\alpha>0$? What else have you tried?

Comment: Yes, $\alpha$ is positive.

Comment: Thanks, is there a lower bound to $\alpha$?

Comment: Aside from the fact that $\alpha$ is positive, it is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Stirling's Asymptotic Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n\log\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)
&=\frac1n\left(n\log(n)-n+\frac12\log(2\pi n)-n\log(n)+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\\
&=-1+\frac1{2n}\log(2\pi n)+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{1/n}=\frac1e\left(1+\frac{\log(2\pi n)}{2n}+O\left(\frac{\log(n)^2}{n^2}\right)\right)
$$
Taking the forward difference, we get
$$
\frac{\large\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{n+1}
-\frac{\large\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}=\frac{1-\log(2\pi n)}{2en^2}+O\left(\frac{\log(n)^2}{n^3}\right)
$$
Thus, if $\alpha\ge2$, the limit is $-\infty$; if $\alpha\lt2$, then the limit is $0$.

---

For example,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt[101]{101!}}{101}-\frac{\sqrt[100]{100!}}{100}
&=0.379824377220339-0.379926893448343\\
&=-0.000102516228004
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\frac{1-\log(200\pi)}{20000e}=-0.000100119259074
$$